# Find an identical file with a different name

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

Is it possible to find a without knowing its name?

I created a file with LaTex, then I copied it into another local directory and renamed the pdf. I don't know any more where the original file is located, but I have the renamed file on hand. I would like to make some modification to my latex file and recreate the pdf.

Since I know the original file is exactly the same as the renamed one except for the name,  is there any way I can find my original file?

Comment: if you created your copy with `cp -p` as I usually do, you may have the date/time/size of the file, and I'd use that to `find` it.  (or I'd `find` all files of the same date (or size..) etc..)

Comment: Choose an appropriate checksum method - like md5.  Then calculate it for your renamed file and all potential files in your file system.  The same file will have the same checksum.

Comment: Yes, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen but the same file will also have the same size which is by far easier to determine than its md5. See [pa4080's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1010622/504066).

Comment: It's not so difficult to use md5sum comparison (alongside the size comparison). I've updated my answer with this idea.

Comment: @perlduck The chance for a false match is much smaller for a proper hash than for the size.

Comment: True @Thorbjørn but theres no point in calculating MD5s of files with different sizes. Sure they will be different. First find all files with the same size as your sample file and only then you need to  calculate a hash for that handful of files.  But not for all files. No need to calc MD5 for all 2GB videos if you're searching a 953 bytes text file.

Comment: @PerlDuck Please remember the context.  If the LaTeX work files are naturally placed in the middle of all the videofiles then it is hard - of course you only look where it is reasonable to look.

Answer (score 5):

When the only difference is the name booth files should have the same content and size.

**1. About the content.** We can compare two files by the command `diff file-1 file-2`. Also we can use this command for a test in this way:

```bsh
diff -q file-1 file-2 > /dev/null && echo 'equal' || echo 'different'
```

**2. About the size.** We can find a file with certain size by the command (where 12672 is the file size in bytes):

```bsh
find /path/to/search -type f -size 12672c -printf '%p\n'
```

Or we can use a range in this way (where 12600-12700 is the file size range in bytes):

```bsh
find /path/to/search -type f -size -12700c -size +12600c -printf '%p\n'
```

Note that, by default the command `find` works recursively.

**3. Combine the two methods** (where `file-1` is our pattern file):

```bsh
find /path/to/search -type f -size -12700c -size +12600c -printf '%p\t' -exec sh -c 'diff -q file-1 "$1" > /dev/null && echo "equal" || echo "different"' sh {} \;
```

**4. Example.** Let's assume we have the following directory structure:

```bsh
$ tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── file-1   # this is the pattern file
├── file-2   # this is almost the same file but wit few additional characters
└── file-3   # this is exact copy of file-1
```

The result of the above command will be:

```bsh
$ find /tmp/test -type f -size -12700c -size +12600c -printf '%p\t' -exec sh -c 'diff -q file-1 "$1" > /dev/null && echo "equal" || echo "different"' sh {} \; 
/tmp/test/file-2        different  # OK: here we have added few additional characters
/tmp/test/file-3        equal      # OK: this is exact copy of file-1
/tmp/test/file-1        equal      # OK: this is file-1 compared to its self
```

Or we can simplify the output by changing our command in this way:

```bsh
$ find /tmp/test -type f -not -name "file-1" -size -12700c -size +12600c \
  -exec sh -c 'diff -q file-1 "$1" > /dev/null && printf "%s\tis equal\n" "$1"' sh {} \;
/tmp/test/file-3        is equal
```

---

**Update from the comments.** The following command finding for file with the same size as the `file-1`, and then the `diff` commas is involved with `--brief` and `--report-identical-files` options:

```bsh
find /path -type f -not -name "file-1" -size $(stat -c%s file-1)c -exec diff -qs file-1 {} \;
Files file-1 and /tmp/test/file-3 are identical
```

We can [compare md5sum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442960/how-to-automate-comparison-of-md5sum-hash-values-for-a-large-number-of-files) of the files in this way:

- Get the md5sum of the pattern file:

  ```bsh
  $ md5sum file-1
  d18b61a77779d69e095be5942f6be7a7  file-1
  ```
- Use it with our command:

  ```bsh
  $ find /path -type f -not -name "file-1" -size $(stat -c%s file-1)c -exec sh -c 'echo "d18b61a77779d69e095be5942f6be7a7 $1" | md5sum -c -' sh {} \;
  /tmp/test/file-3: OK
  ```

Comment: +1 for using the size in first place. By the way, the diff command line can be simplified: `diff -qs file-1 file-2` will do the job :-)

Comment: @sudodus The `-qs` probably speeds up `diff`because it can stop comparing the files when the first mismatch is found.

Comment: `cmp -s` is better than `diff` when the goal is simply to tell if two files are equal.

Comment: You need to learn about xargs

Comment: @JohnKugelman, I followed your advice and started to use `cmp -s` for similar cases: https://askubuntu.com/a/1014921/566421 :-)

Answer (score 3):

- You can search for a particular string with `grep -rl "string"`
  (-r for recursive, finding the string in files, -l for showing the filename, not the string)

Comment: you shouldn't use the -i as mentioned in @mrfred489 's link as files are identical and it can slow things down

Answer (score 3):

This might take a while, but it should be effective and reliable. It assumes you are using Bash. Replace `file` with the name of your renamed file:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for i in **; do [ -f "$i" ] && cmp --silent file "$i" && echo "$i"; done
```

- `shopt -s globstar` turns on recursive globbing with `**`. You can turn it off with `shopt -u globstar`, but it is off by default and will be off when you open a new shell.
- `for i in **` loop over all files below this one. Run the command from the highest level directory that might contain the file or the directory with the file or the directory... (apply recursion to this sentence!)
- `[ -f "$i" ] &&` if the file is a regular file that exists then...
- `cmp --silent file "$i" &&` if there is no difference between `file` and the file being examined (ie if `cmp` exits successfully), then...
- `echo $i` print the relative path of the file (this also prints the path of `file` itself, but I didn't see much benefit in fixing that).

Thanks to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900693/6192153) for the `cmp` method of comparing files.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for (or okay with) a GUI application, you may try the "*FSlint Janitor*" application. You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install fslint
```

#### How to use the application:

Once installed, follow the steps below.

1. Launch the application.
2. Select the "Duplicates" option (1) to search *files with the same content*.
3. Click on the "+ Add" button (2) and select the directories to look for files (make sure the "recurse" option is checked to include sub-directories).
4. Click on the "Find" button (3) and wait.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Grep can find it quickly

When used properly, the `grep` command can find the duplicate quickly. You must be careful not to search the whole file system or it will take **days** to complete. I recently documented this here: [`grep`ing all files for a string takes a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-53-hours)

For optimum speed use:

```
grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e 'String in file'
```

If your file might be on a Windows directory remove the `mnt` directory.

If you know the file is within the `/home` directory someplace you can shorten the command:

```
grep -rnw '/home' -e 'String in file'
```